# In Chulin 95b, it states that "Rav never partook of a seudas reshus", is that referring to why he didn't eat the meat, or anything at all?

Tags: talmud-gemara, meal-seudah, agada-stories-legends

In Chullin 95b when describing why Rav didn't partake of some meat it says:

> אלא סעודת הרשות הואי ורב לא מתהני מסעודת הרשות (rather it was an optional meal and Rav did not partake of optional meals).

My question is, if Seudas Reshus is being used figuratively (i.e a festive meal, as the author of [this article uses it](http://matzav.com/the-shalom-zachar-and-the-shabbos-kiddush-for-girls/)), or does it literally mean a seudah, any bread meal.

The first understanding seems to make sense since the entire issue in question is regarding the meat.

Comment: Note: based on Rashi and the referenced Gemara (Pesachim 49a), where the example given is an Am Haaretz marrying the daughter of a Talmid Chacham, that seems to imply the first opinion, a festive meal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fei23 brings an interesting proof from Pesachim 49a where it seems to imply that it is a festive meal.  I feel the same way, but here are some sources on the topic.  Neither of these addresses it head-on, but should shed some light.

Daf al Hadaf there quotes the Imrei Emes that this only referred to a large (presumably festive) meal:

> החדושי הרי"מ זצ"ל מגור תמה. למה לא אכל אצל אדם שהזמינו לאכול ע"כ. ונכדו, כ"ק אדמו"ר בעל האמרי אמת זצ"ל השיב בזה: אפשר לומר, שדוקא בסעודה העשויה לרבים לא אכל, אבל אצל יחיד אכל, כדאי' בגמ' פסחים מט. כל סעודה שאינה של מצוה אין ת"ח רשאי להנות ממנה, כגון מאי אר"י כגון בת כהן לישראל וכו', משמע שאצל יחיד מותר ע"כ.

He later quotes the Magen Avraham (OC 333) that it includes any meal where one is a guest.  Here is the Magen Avraham inside:

> צורך אורחים. אמרי' בחולין פ"ז סעודת הרשות הוי ורב לא מתהני מסעודת הרשות ופירש"י סעודת הרשו' בת ת"ח לע"ה ע"כ משמע דרב דהי' אורח שם מקרי סעוד' הרשו' עסי' תקס"ח ס"ב וכ"כ בתשובת מהר"מ סי' תר"ה וכשסועד עם אורחי' הוי סעוד' הרשו' רק שבע"ה המזמנם עושה מצוה וכצ"ל כאן: )